# Unable to veryfy GitHub webhook token

Tags: laravel, github, webhooks, sha1, hmac

I have GitHub header verification but when trying to compare my hash with webhook hash it always fails.
According to [this article](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/securing/#validating-payloads-from-github) Github hashes with HMAC but if i do my hash on my end it never produces correct hash.
Can you please advice?

My github settings

[image]

My code

```
$githubtoken = Request::header('X-Hub-Signature');  // sha1=856e168484cd6e407d5098dd61948b88890df86f
$myTokenHash = 'sha1='.hash_hmac('sha1', 'githubstring', ''); // sha1=f38a5636b9792d771ef75fe8d1ac06f78cfad194

if ($myTokenHash !== $githubtoken) {
    // always end up here, tokens are not identical
    throw new Exception('Invalid  token');
}

// never getting here
```

Example of what I'm getting in header from GitHub

```
X-Hub-Signature: sha1=856e168484cd6e407d5098dd61948b88890df86f
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out. Houpefully it helps

```
$githubtoken = Request::header('X-Hub-Signature');
$myTokenHash = 'sha1=' . hash_hmac('sha1',request()->getContent(), 'githubstring');
```